# Strange behaviour when changing value of list in a list

Tags: python, list

While coding on a python project I noticed a strange behavior when I tried to change the value of a list in another list.

**Not working code:**

```
lst = []
to_add = [None,None,None]

for i in range(3):
    lst.append(to_add)

for i in range(3):
    lst[i][0] = anotherslistoflists[i][0]
```

To my surprise this example gave unexpected results. To be specific, every lst[i][0] got assigned with the same value which was the first element from the last index of the "anotherlistoflists" list.

**Result example** (when printing lst)

```
("word1",None,None)
("word1",None,None)
("word1",None,None)
```

**Working code:**

```
lst = []

for i in range(5):
    lst.append([None,None,None])

# same code as above
```

**Result example2** (expected result)

```
("word1",None,None)
("word2",None,None)
("word3",None,None)
```

Of course, as you can see the problem is solved but I was wondering why the first code does not work. Something is probably wrong with the "to_add" list but I don't understand what is the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending **the same list**, `to_add`, three times. Then, once you modify it, all three items which point to it will reflect the same change. If you want to create a new copy with the same values, you could use the built-in [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) function:

```
for i in range(3):
    lst.append(list(to_add))
```

Comment: Ok so by doing list(to_add) I am creating a new independent instance of to_add list. I get it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the same list, `to_add` to `lst`:

```
>>> a = [None]
>>> b = [a]
>>> c = [a]
>>> print a, b, c
[None] [[None]] [[None]]
>>> a[0] = 1
>>> print a, b, c
[1] [[1]] [[1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you are not adding a copy of `add_to_list` you are actually adding that exact list over and over, so when you change it later you're changing the real `add_to_list` and everywhere that refers to it.  In the second case you're adding a new list containing `None` each time, and modifying different lists each time through